# Is the value returned by system() the same as "$?"?

Tags: perl

When I do `system()` calls in Perl, I usually inspect the return code according to the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). *Well, I thought so.* Most of the time `$rc!=0` is sufficient for me. Recently I helped two people here which had trouble with `system()` calls when running their .cgi scripts under apache. I instructed them to examine the `$rc` of

```
my $rc = system(...);
```

and linked them to the `system()` docs. Then I looked closer and noticed the docs aren't really talking about the `$rc` but instead about `$?` and I felt a bit embarassed and the following question arose:

Is there a difference between:

```
system(...);
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

and

```
my $rc = system(...);
if ($rc == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($rc & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($rc & 127),  ($rc & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $rc >> 8;
}
```

Or, for short, is `$rc` equal to `$?` for `system()`?

I looked through the docs of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html), and [$?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) but it's not quite clear to me. Did I do wrong for the last 15 years by using `$rc`?

Comment: If you capture the result to `$rc` there's no chance of `$?` changing on you before you get around to using that value.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I added a comment to the accepted answer which also applies to your comment. Using `$rc` seems the cleaner way to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the return value of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) *should* equal `$?`.

However since `$?` does not *only* apply to `system` calls and `$?` is a global variable, it could be overwritten by other actions that are occurring. From `perldoc -v '$?'` these include:

> $CHILD_ERROR
>
> $?
>
> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick ("``") command, successful call to "wait()" or "waitpid()", or from the "system()" operator.

It is far safer to store the value immediately then compare:

```
my $rc = system('ls myfile.txt');
if ( $rc >> 8 != 0 ) {
   # do something because ls exited with an error
}
```

Comment: Great! That's what I wanted to hear and make sure. Thank you. I'm aware of `$?`'s volatility (like errno in C) and only use it if there's no explicit $rc available (like with backticks). I prefer explicit vars anyway and even avoid `$_` when possible. IMHO readability and maintainability suffer from using too many _magic_ vars. So I'll stick with `$rc`. :-)

Comment: `$?` is pretty much exactly the same as C's venerable `errno` which means it has a lot of the same problems. Magical global variables sure seemed like a great idea once, but thankfully we've moved on.

Comment: @tadman Actually, `$!` is pretty much exactly the same as `errno` (it simply retrieves the current value of `errno`). `$?` is slightly different because it gets set by each `wait` or pipe close, even if they succeed (`$!` is only valid immediately after a failure). But you're right about global variables.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Good point. Another reason why `$?` is confusingly unreliable compared to direct capture of the return value.